# How to handle action in EmberJS in nested Component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components, action

so I have nested components in EmberJS and can't manage to properly handle their actions.

I have route `Create` and in its template Component `pixel-grid`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        {{pixel-grid}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">

    </div>
</div>
```

In `pixel-grid` template i have component named `pixel-cell`:

```
<table class="mx-auto">
    {{#each (range 0 panelWidth) as |row|}}
    <tr class="table-row">
        {{#each (range 0 panelHeight) as |cell|}}
        <th class="table-cell">
            {{pixel-cell onClick=(action 'changeColor')}}
        </th>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

Component `pixel-cell` have an empty template since I don't need it for now. In `pixel-cell` component js file I have:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
export default Component.extend({
    classNames: ['cell', 'clickable'],
    tagName: 'div',

    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
    },
});
```

This code obviously do not compile since I did not handle this action.
But..

I tried to set action in `pixel-cell` but then Ember told me that `pixel-grid` should have that action.
So I did put this `changeColor` action in `pixel-grid` -> that doesn't work.

So I tried to handle this by something like this in `pixel-cell` js:

```
click() {
    this.sendAction('changeColor');
},
```

-> that doesn't work.

I have no idea how it should work ;/ I tried to read guides but still can't manage that. Please help.

Comment: `Component.sendAction()` has been deprecated in favor of closure actions: emberjs.com/deprecations/v3.x/#toc_ember-component-send-action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally never used `sendAction`. Instead, you should pass actions as attributes from parents to child components, then invoke them within child components. This approach is much easier to reason about as well as other benefits which https://emberigniter.com/send-closure-actions-up-data-owner/ explains in great details.

In your example:

pixel-grid.js:

```
export default Component.extend({
  actions: {
    changeColor(cell) {
      console.log("CELL ACTION");
      console.log(cell);
      cell.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
  }
});
```

pixel-grid.hbs:

```
{{pixel-cell handleColorChange=(action 'changeColor')}}
```

pixel-cell.js:

```
export default Component.extend({
    classNames: ['cell', 'clickable'],
    tagName: 'div',

    click: function () {
        // Invoke parent action and pass this element as the argument
        this.get("handleColorChange")(this.element);
    }
});
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using the `click` event.

Answer (score 1):

https://ember-twiddle.com/e04e318489bcc8e9e921e849c9fb9e9e?openFiles=templates.components.pixel-cell.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.pixel-grid.hbs

I have create a twiddle to show you a sample action passing from parent component to child component. You can refer the above url to understand it easier.

Instead of sendAction, I have used a concept called closure actions which is the norm in Ember going forward.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against handling actions on component elements. Instead always use closure actions!

If you do `{{some-component onClick=(action 'changeColor')}}` you need the action `changeColor` on the corresponding, *not* inside `some-component`! However you probably want to use it inside `some-component` like this:

```
<button onclick={{@changeColor}}>...</button>
```

In your case I would set `tagName: ''` for the `pixel-cell` component and add this template:

```
<div onclick={{@changeColor}}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did manage to get this to work. It looks like this:

`pixel-grid` template:

```
<table class="mx-auto">
    {{#each (range 0 panelWidth) as |row|}}
    <tr class="table-row">
        {{#each (range 0 panelHeight) as |cell|}}
        <th class="table-cell">
            {{pixel-cell}}
        </th>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

`pixel-cell` component js file:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
export default Component.extend({
    classNames: ['cell', 'clickable'],
    tagName: 'div',

    click: function () {
        this.sendAction('changeColor', this);
    },

    changeColor(cell) {
        console.log("CELL ACTION");
        console.log(cell);
        cell.element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
});
```

Others files are empty (only panelHeight and panel Width in `pixel-grid` js file).
Is this a good way of doing this?